# How to get last cell index path in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, indexing

I am building an `IOS` application where I am using `tableView`. Now when I reached to last `cell` I load +10 data from localDB.

After fetching the data I reloaded the `tableView` that I don't need in place of reload I want to used updated `tableView`. for that SOF suggested me below code.

```
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];

[[self tableView] reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:____ withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

I don't what should be there in `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` value. Please can some help me in understanding this above line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the indexPath of the last row in last section like this.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1) inSection:(numberOfSections - 1)];
```

Here, numberOfSections is the value you return from numberOfSectionsInTableView: method. And, numberOfRowsInLastSection is the value you return from numberOfRowsInSection: method for the last section in the table view.

Comment: This is the error coming - 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 15 from section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: u will get ur ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706254/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-attempt-to-insert-row-0-into-section

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload cells, because there are no cells after your 10th cell. You want your users to see more cells when they get to the last one as in a news app. The solution is to inset more rows below, here is how:

1- create the rows you want to insert

```
NSMutableArray *newRows = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0]];
```

3- update your data source array 

2- `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: newRows, UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

Comment: what you return from numberOfCellsInTableView ?