# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making an iOS app but I keep getting this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'
```

I have researched this question for 2 days now but I don't know what's wrong. I am putting my code down below.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var loggedInUser:AnyObject?
var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?

@IBOutlet weak var aivLoading: UIActivityIndicatorView!

@IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

var posts = [NSDictionary]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    self.databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        self.loggedInUserData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.databaseRef.child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

            self.posts.insert(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary, at: 0)
            self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
        }){(error) in
            ProgressHUD.showError("There was an error, try again")
        }
    }

    self.homeTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.homeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: HomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["text"] as! String

    cell.configure("Anonymous", post: post)
    return cell
}

}
```

In my code, it refers to a dequeueReusableCell, with the identifier `HomeTableViewCell`, which is a Swift file. Here is the code for that Swift file:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameConstant: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var post: UITextView!


    override open func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    open func configure(_ nameConstant: String, post: String)  {
        self.post.text = post
        self.nameConstant.text = "Anonymous"
    }

}
```

I know there are similar questions to mine but a lot of those are in Objective-C. I've looked at the Swift ones too but they don't help.

If anyone has any ideas to fix this that would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706254/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-attempt-to-insert-row-0-into-section)

Comment: Have you set the delegate/datasource of your tableview to your view controller?

Comment: Like I said DonMag, that question is for Objective-C. I'm having a problem in Swift.

Comment: Yeah I made the tableview an IBOutlet of my view controller. And I defined the formatting for the tableviewcell in a different view controller named "HomeTableViewCell" @dan

Comment: In `viewDidLoad()`, before`self.databaseRef.child(...`, call: `homeTableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: There's a bigger issue here. You're appending the snapshot to an array - and assuming its the dataSource for the tableview, which is fine, but then inserting a row manually into your tableView? You're not going to want to do that. Populate your tableView datasource first and then call tableView.reloadData(). Or, if you are wanting to reverse the order being read in, insert each snapshot into row 0 of the array, then tableView.realodData(). Oh, why repeatedly insert row 0 in the tableView to start with?

Comment: So add tableView.reloadData() after the viewDidLoad method, right? And is there any line of code I should remove?

Comment: 1) Both *self.homeTableView.rowHeight* and *self.homeTableView.estimatedRowHeight* will be called before the array is populated so those should be moved to within the closure.  2) It's not clear why rows are being manually inserted into the homeTableView. Generally, a tableView uses a dataSource and populates accordingly. 3) Where is the tableView being updated (tableView.reloadData())? In the tableView:cellForRowAt, why the complex function to return a row from the array? If the are 10 rows, and the tableView need row 3 (indexPath.row), just return the needed text from the object at array[3]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you're always returning 1 for number of rows. But i guess you should be returning posts.count right? Every time you `insertRows(at:...` the table checks consistency through the delegate. There's also something weird, you're appending to your list (`self.posts.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)`) but then you're inserting row 0-0?, I'll assume you want to insert new post to the top. Moreover if you have just one section, you don't need to implement the method.

So here's the code (I'm assuming the firebase and cell configuration code is correct):

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
var loggedInUser:AnyObject?
var loggedInUserData:NSDictionary?

@IBOutlet weak var aivLoading: UIActivityIndicatorView!

@IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

var posts = [NSDictionary]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loggedInUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

    self.databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        self.loggedInUserData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.databaseRef.child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

            self.posts.insert(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary, at: 0)
            self.homeTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
        }){(error) in
            ProgressHUD.showError("There was an error, try again")
        }
    }

    self.homeTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.homeTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: HomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    let post = posts[(self.posts.count-1) - (indexPath.row)]["text"] as! String

    cell.configure("Anonymous", post: post)
    return cell
}

}
```

I hope it fixes your problem ;)

Comment: Hey so I didn't get a chance to try the code until just now, and it still doesn't work. I'm updating the question if you could just take a look at what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So you're still getting the same error? can you re-check if you're assigning the delegate? Because what you told to Dan (that asked about the delegate) is not related with delegate. 
Just to make sure: can you just do `homeTableView.delegate = self `just after `super.viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: Lemme know if you find a solution please

Comment: so now you're not getting the error you posted, then the problem is solved. I don't really understand what to find solution for :D